# Error in displaying the videos

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gtk, gtk2

I have logged into a remote VM using SSH. I am trying to run a bash script (.sh) that would fire up a video. However I am facing difficulties in doing this. I have set up the DISPLAY variable to various values ranging from :0.0 to :0 as per various other answers on SO; however I still face this error. I have installed the libgtk2.0-dev package while installing OpenCV via ansible script.

I have also installed the following libraries for supporting video formats:

- libavcodec-dev
- libavformat-dev
- libswscale-dev
- libv4l-dev

Is there someway in which I can display the video?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I have set up the DISPLAY variable to various values ranging from :0.0 to :0 as per various other answers on SO

It is not about setting DISPLAY variable to some arbitrary value. If you want to run the video on your local X server, you need to create a X11 forwarding channel, while connecting to the server (`-Y` switch to `ssh).

Still, the actual error you see would be very helpful.

Comment: @ridgy It is also `-Y` if you had a look into the manual page. The `-X` itself does not work with default configuration.